# Filter with several nullable conditions an IEnumerable - List using lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, where-clause, conditional-statements

I use .NET 4.5 and VS 2012.

I have a classes model (from Xml Deserialize) and I have now "filter" it.

I have nullables values for several conditions.

Which is best good practice for do it using lambda expressions ?

I have this code:

```
    public static List<MyDto> ListarEntornosYContenidoEntorno(int? id, string name, int? id2, string name2, string entorno, bool? shouldBe, string mode)
    {
        IEnumerable<MyDto> list = Model.Environments;

        if (id.HasValue)
            list = list.Where(item => item.IdCiaDespliegue.Equals(id.Value));

        if (!name.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
            list = list.Where(item => item.NombreCiaDespliegue.Equals(name));

        if (id2.HasValue)
            list = list.Where(item => item.IdContenidoEntorno.Equals(id2.Value));

        if (!name2.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
            list = list.Where(item => item.ContenidoEntorno.Equals(name2));

        if (!entorno.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
            list = list.Where(item => item.Entorno.Equals(entorno));

        if (shouldBe.HasValue)
            list = list.Where(item => item.DebeEtiquetar.Equals(shouldBe));

        if (!mode.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
            list = list.Where(item => item.Modo.Equals(mode));

        return list.ToList();

    }
```

Comment: That looks fine, do you have a problem?

Comment: I would find good practice,  more readable and clear.

Comment: If you want to use one method for all filters your approach seems to be very clear, isnt it?

Comment: These kind of questions belong on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following (not sure if it's more readable):

```
IEnumerable<MyDto> list = Model.Environments;

return list.Where(item => !id.HasValue                       || item.IdCiaDespliegue == id.Value)
           .Where(item => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)    || item.NombreCiaDespliegue == name)
           .Where(item => !id2.HasValue                      || item.IdContenidoEntorno == id2.Value)
           .Where(item => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name2)   || item.ContenidoEntorno == name2)
           .Where(item => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entorno) || item.Entorno == entorno)
           .Where(item => !shouldBe.HasValue                 || item.DebeEtiquetar == shouldBe)
           .Where(item => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mode)    || item.Modo == mode)
           .ToList();
```

The trick is just to return `true` when your selector is null or empty, so that no items will be filtered out.

Note that I replaced all your `.Equals` with `==` because in this case they are equivalent, and `==` is more readable in my opinion.

Comment: This is not more but less readable and even more error-prone than OP's code. It's also more difficult to debug.

Comment: Why `x ? true : y` instead of `x || y` ?

Answer (score 1):

I've given you a way to generalize this below for your nullable ints; I'm sure you can do something similar for the strings. Also, you should consider changing your API so this method accepts a list of "filter conditions" or similar instead.

```
var intMap = new Dictionary<int?, Func<Environment, int>> 
{
    { id, item => item.IdCiaDespliegue },
    { id2, item => item.IdContenidoEntorno },
    { entorno, item => item.DebeEtiquetar }
}

var list = Model.Environments;

foreach(var pair in intMap)
{
    if(pair.Key != null)
        list = list.Where(item => pair.Value(item).Equals(pair.Key.Value));
}
```